# Make an SKSpriteNode fall when the screen is not being tapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit, flappy-bird-clone

I would like to have an SKSpriteNode start to fall when the screen is not being tapped(like in flappy bird). I have SKActions that move the object up which are called in the touchesBegan method and I would like the object to fall until the next tap or it hits the ground.

Comment: Either use physics or move your sprite down each scene update.
You should also show some work, what have you tried, what didn't work, not just expect someone to copy flappy bird for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trying setting your gravity in the game to 
`self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,-9.8);`
and setting your SKSpriteNode to dynamic.

> test.physicsbody.dynamic = YES;